# Erro no cadastro de post com texto vazio

Tags: php, html, mysql

O código de cadastro do post é este:

```
                    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['cadastrar'])){
        $titulo         = trim(strip_tags($_POST['titulo']));
        $data           = trim(strip_tags($_POST['data']));
        $descricao      = $_POST['descricao'];
        $exibir         = trim(strip_tags($_POST['exibir']));




        //INFO IMAGEM
    $file       = $_FILES['img'];
    $numFile    = count(array_filter($file['name']));

    //PASTA
    $folder     = '../upload/postagens/';

    //REQUISITOS
    $permite    = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png');
    $maxSize    = 1024 * 1024 * 5;

    //MENSAGENS
    $msg        = array();
    $errorMsg   = array(
        1 => 'O arquivo no upload é maior do que o limite definido em upload_max_filesize no php.ini.',
        2 => 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho em MAX_FILE_SIZE que foi especificado no formulário HTML',
        3 => 'o upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente',
        4 => 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo'
    );

    if($numFile <= 0){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    Selecione uma imagem e tente novamente!
                </div>';
    }
    else if($numFile >=2){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    Você ultrapassou o limite de upload. Selecione apenas uma foto e tente novamente!
                </div>';
    }else{
        for($i = 0; $i < $numFile; $i++){
            $name   = $file['name'][$i];
            $type   = $file['type'][$i];
            $size   = $file['size'][$i];
            $error  = $file['error'][$i];
            $tmp    = $file['tmp_name'][$i];

            $extensao = @end(explode('.', $name));
            $novoNome = rand().".$extensao";

            if($error != 0)
                echo $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> ".$errorMsg[$error];
            else if(!in_array($type, $permite))
                echo $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem não suportada!";
            else if($size > $maxSize)
                echo $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem ultrapassa o limite de 5MB";
            else{

                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $folder.'/'.$novoNome)){


        $insert = "INSERT into tb_postagens (titulo, data, imagem, descricao, exibir) VALUES (:titulo, :data, :imagem, :descricao, :exibir)";

    try{
        $result = $conexao->prepare($insert);
        $result->bindParam(':titulo', $titulo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':data', $data, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':imagem', $novoNome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':descricao', $descricao, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':exibir', $exibir, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $result->execute();
        $contar = $result->rowCount();
        if($contar>0){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-success">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                  <strong>Sucesso!</strong> O post foi cadastrado.
            </div>';
        }else{
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                  <strong>Erro ao cadastrar!</strong> Não foi possível cadastrar o post.
            </div>';
        }           
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e;
    }   






                }else
                    $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Desculpe! Ocorreu um erro...";

            }

            foreach($msg as $pop)
            echo '';
                //echo $pop.'<br>';
        }
    }


    }


 ?>
```

O formulário para cadastrar o post é este:

```
<div class="w3-card-4 w3-margin w3-white">

<div class="w3-container" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-left: 20px;">                                       
<h2><b> Adicionar Post </b></h2><br>
<div class="tab-pane" id="formcontrols">
<form id="edit-profile" class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</div>

<div class="w3-container" style="padding-left: 20px;">                                       
    <p>
        <label>Título</label> <br>
        <input style="width: 300px; height: 40px; border-top: 1px; border-left: 1px; border-right: 1px; border-color: lightgray;" 
        type="text" name="titulo" placeholder="Digite o título" id="titulo" required>
    </p>
</div>

<div class="w3-container" style="padding-left: 20px;">                                       
    <p>
        <label>Data</label> <br>
        <input style="width: 120px; height: 40px; height: 40px; border-top: 1px; border-left: 1px; border-right: 1px; border-color: lightgray;" type="text" name="data" id="data" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa"
        maxlength="10" onkeypress="mascaraData( this, event )" required>
    </p>    
</div>  

<div class="w3-container" style="padding-left: 20px;">                                       
    <p>
        <label>Imagem</label> <br>
        <input style="padding-top: 10px;" type="file" id="imagem" name="img[]" required>
    </p>                                
</div>

<?php if($nivelLogado == 1) { ?>
<div class="w3-container" style="padding-left: 20px;">                                       
    <p>
        <label>Exibir</label> <br>
        <select style="width: 80px; height: 35px;" id="exibir" name="exibir">
            <option>Sim</option>
            <option>Não</option>
        </select>
    </p>     
</div>  
<?php } ?>                                     

<div class="w3-container" style="padding-left: 20px;">                                                           
    <p>
        <textarea style="width: 1000px;" name="descricao" id="descricao" rows="15"></textarea>
    </p>
</div>

<div class="w3-container" style="padding-left: 20px;">                                                                         
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 30px;">
                <p><input style="width:100px; height:40px; background:#333; color:white; border:none;"
                type="reset" name="cancelar" value="Cancelar" class="w3-button w3-black w3-section"/></p>
            </td> 
            <td style="padding-bottom: 30px; padding-left: 10px;">
                <p><input style="width:100px; height:40px; background:#333; color:white; border:none;"
                type="submit" name="cadastrar" value="Salvar" class="w3-button w3-black w3-section"/></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="w3-container" style="padding-left: 20px;">                                       
</form>  


                    </div> <!-- /widget-content -->
                </div> <!-- /widget -->
            </div><!-- span 12 -->


    </div><!-- row -->        



        </div>
        <!-- /span6 --> 
      </div>
      <!-- /row --> 
    </div>
    <!-- /container --> 
  </div>
  <!-- /main-inner --> 
</div>
<!-- /main -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="editor/nicEdit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() }); </script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
function mascaraData( campo, e )
{
    var kC = (document.all) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
    var data = campo.value;

    if( kC!=8 && kC!=46 )
    {
        if( data.length==2 )
        {
            campo.value = data += '/';
        }
        else if( data.length==5 )
        {
            campo.value = data += '/';
        }
        else
            campo.value = data;
    }
}
</script>
```

Porém `descricao` não está sendo salva no banco de dados.

Obs.: eu tenho outros sistemas de cadastro: de login, comentários, etc e estão funcionando corretamente.

Comment: Há algum erro em `$conexao->errorInfo` (após o `prepare`)?

Comment: Coloca a estrutura da tabela.

Comment: Provavelmente o erro está no nome da coluna da tabela ou o tamanho definido nela é menor do que o valor enviado, por exemplo, foi definido `descricao varchar(25)` e foi enviado uma string com 30 caracteres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está usando um plugin que não envia o valor do `textearea`. Ele substitui o `textarea` por uma `div` editável, logo o `textarea` não contem o texto digitado.

Para contornar isso, você pode ao submeter o formulário, inserir o conteúdo da `div` no `textarea` instanciado pelo plugin.

Insira um evento `onclick` no botão `submit` para chamar uma função que fará isso:

```
               função
                 ↓
<input onclick="nic()" style="width:100px; height:40px; background:#333; color:white; border:none;" type="submit" name="cadastrar" value="Salvar" class="w3-button w3-black w3-section"/>
```

E a função no `script`:

```
<script>
function nic(){
   var texto = nicEditors.findEditor('descricao').nicInstances[0].editorContain.innerHTML;
   document.body.querySelector("#descricao").value = texto;
}
</script>
```

Desta forma o PHP:

```
$descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
```

receberá o valor do `textarea` `name="descricao"` normalmente.